# Perl Script can't use Tie::File

Tags: perl, unix

I'm trying to run a perl script which uses the Tie::File module.

What it basically is supposed to do is read in all the files from the current directory, cut off the last line of the first document, then the first and last line of every other document and the first line of the last document, then write everything to a new document.

When I'm trying to run my script (which might have some mistakes in it...I'd be happy if someone could correct them if you find any) I'm getting an errormessage:

```
Can't locate object method "TIEARRAY" via package "TIE:File" at script.pl line 28, <$fh> line 7.
```

I've marked line 28 in the code.

I've installed the latest version of Tie::File and checked with

```
cpan Tie::File
```

and

```
cpan Tie::Array
```

if everything is installed, I received Tie::Array is up to date (v1.06) and Tie::File is up to date (v1.00) from the terminal, so they have to be installed correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd;
use Tie::File;
use Tie::Array;
my $cwd = getcwd();
my $buff = '';

# Get all files in cwd.
#my @files = grep { -f && /\.txt$/ } readdir $cwd;
my @files = grep ( -f ,<*.txt>);      


# Cut off footer of first (files[0]) file
print 'Opening' . $files[0] . "\n";

use Tie::File;
tie (@lines, Tie::File, $files[0]) or die "can't update $file: $!";
delete $lines[-1];


#  Cut off header and footer of $files [1] to $files[-2]
for ($a = 1, $a < $#files-1, $a++){

    print 'Opening' . $file . "\n";

    use Tie::FILE;
    tie (@lines, TIE::File, $files[$a]) or die "can't update $file: $!"; ####this is line 28
    delete $lines[0];
    delete $lines[-1];

    open (FILE, "<", $files[$a]) or die $!;
    while (my $line =<FILE>) {
        $buff .= $line;
    }
    close FILE;

}

print 'Opening' . $files[-1] . "\n";

use Tie::FILE;
tie (@lines, TIE::File, $files[-1]) or die "can't update $file: $!";
delete $lines[0];

open (lastfile, "<", $files[-1]) or die "can't open $files[-1]: $!";
while (my $line =<lastfile>) {
    $buff .= $line;
}
close lastfile;



# Write the buffer to a new file.
my $allfilename = $cwd.'/Trace.txt';
print 'Writing all files into new file: ' . $allfilename . "\n";

open $outputfile, ">".$allfilename or die $!;
# Write the buffer into the output file.
print $outputfile $buff;

close $outputfile;
```

Comment: You only need 'use Tie::File' once.

Comment: Also File and FILE are not the same. Neither are TIE and Tie.

Comment: use Tie::File multiple times doesnt hurt, still i removed it....the problem also didnt lie in FILE, but in TIE::File, which is supposed to be Tie::File...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is frankly a bit of a mess. You seem to be trying things in the hope that they work but without any real reasoning.

I have refactored your code to do what I think you want below. Here are the main changes I have made

- You must *always* add `use strict` and `use warnings` to *every* Perl program you write, and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. Those simple measures alone will save you from a lot of simple errors that you will otherwise overlook
- You don't need `Tie::Array` or `Cwd`. They are irrelevant to this program
- Your `tie` statement needs a *string* as the second parameter, so you need to use `'Tie::File'` instead of `Tie::File`
- Your output file `Trace.txt` will be found by the `<*.txt>` glob, so unless you take measures to specifically exclude it your program will copy trim the first and last lines and copy the contents of that file to itself. In my program I have simply checked in the `for` loop whether the current file name is `Trace.txt` and skipped it if so
- There is no point in accumulating the data in a buffer `$buff`. You may as well just write the data to the file as you encounter it
- The lines in the tied array `@lines` have no trailing newline, so you will presumably want to add one when you write to the file
- As has been discussed in the comments, you are using `Tie::FILE` and `TIE::File` as well as the correct `Tie::File`. And you have written `use Tie::File` (and its variations) four times in total. Sure it doesn't stop the program from working, but it is a major indication of foggy thinking, and that you are just statements around in the hope that they make your program work
- Using `delete` on anything other than the *last* element of an array just sets that element to `undef`: it doesn't delete it, and all that happens in the tied file is that the text is removed leaving just a newline. You need to use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) instead
- Separating your files into the first, the last, and the rest is unnecessary and makes your code illegible. In my program below I have used a single loop that removes the first line of the file unless it's the first fil, and removes the last line of the file unless it's the last file. It's far easier to read that way
- Lastly, I'm not at all sure that you want to remove the first and last lines from the *existing* files, or if you just want all the data copied to your output file *except* those lines. I have written my program according to your specification, but bear in mind that the files will get shorter by two lines *every time you run it*, and that probably isn't the effect you want. If you have a different requirement and can't see how to modify the code to achieve it then please ask another question.

I hope this helps you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my @files = grep -f, glob '*.txt';

my $all_filename = 'Trace.txt';
open my $out_fh, '>', $all_filename or die qq{Unable to open "$all_filename" for output: $!};

for my $i ( 0 .. $#files ) {

  my $file = $files[$i];
  next if $file eq $all_filename;

  print "Opening $file\n";

  tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $file or die qq{Can't update "$file": $!};
  splice @lines,  0, 1 unless $i == 0;
  splice @lines, -1, 1 unless $i == $#files;

  print $out_fh "$_\n" for @lines;
}

close $out_fh;
```

Comment: @Buitenlander: I have modified this solution in response to your comment in a later (!) question that it doesn't output anything. I had made the mistake of using `untie @lines` to close and update each the input *before* copying its contents to the output file. I have simply removed the `untie` altogether because it will happen automatically when `@lines` goes out of scope at the end of the loop. However this isn't much use to you because, as I suspected, you don't want the input files modified. But it's nice to get it right for anyone else that uses the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Perl module names are case sensitive. The module is called Tie::File, not Tie::FILE or TIE::File.