# Merge txt files in Perl, but modify them before, leaving original files untouched

Tags: perl

I've already posted a question and fixed the problem in my code, but now my "specification has changed" so to say, and now I need to change some things about it.

Here's a code that takes all .txt files from the current directory, cuts off the last line of the first file, the first and the last line of every following file and the first line of the last file and writes everything in a new file (in other words: merge all files, deleting header and footer so that the new file has only one header and one footer).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use Tie::File;
use Tie::Array;
my $cwd = getcwd();
my $buff = '';

# Get all files in cwd.
my @files = grep ( -f ,<*.txt>);

#  Cut off header and footer of $files [1] to $files[$#files-1], 
#  but only footer of $files[0] and header of $#files[$#files]
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#files; $i++) {

    print 'Opening ' . $files[$i] . "\n";

    tie (@lines, Tie::File, $files[$i]) or die "can't update $file: $!";
    splice @lines, 0, 1 unless $i == 0;
    splice @lines, -1, 1 unless $i == $#files;
    untie @lines;

    open (file, "<", $files[$i]) or die "can't update $file: $!";

    while (my $line =<file>) {
        $buff .= $line;
    }
    close file;

}

# Write the buffer to a new file.
my $allfilename = $cwd.'/Trace.txt';
print 'Writing all files into new file: ' . $allfilename . "\n";

open $outputfile, ">".$allfilename or die "can't write to new file $outputfile: $!";
# Write the buffer into the output file.
print $outputfile $buff;

close $outputfile;
```

My problem: I **don't** want to change the original files, but my code does exactly that and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. The simplest way (simple meaning not having to change too much code) would now be, to just copy all the files to a tmp directory, messing around with them and leaving the original files untouched. Problem: a simple use of dircopy doesn't do it for me, since you have to give a new tmp dir to the dircopy function, making the code only usable for Windows or UNIX systems (but I need portability).

The next approach would be to make use of the File::Temp module but I'm really having trouble with the docs on this one.

Does anybody have a good idea on this one?

Comment: only ~30kb, so don't have to worry about file size too much

Comment: Another approach would be to just skip the lines that are not wanted in the "write to new file section", but i'm not really sure how to do that...

Comment: Please *always* `use strict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not use Tie::File. Or is there a reason you do this, for example all your files together do not fit your memory or something?
A version very close to your current implementation would be something like the following (untested) code. It just skips the part where you update the file, just to reopen and read it afterwards. (Note that this is certainly not a very effective or overly elegant way to do this, it just sticks to your implementation as close as possible)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Cwd;
# use Tie::File;
# use Tie::Array;
my $cwd = getcwd();
my $buff = '';

# Get all files in cwd.
my @files = grep ( -f ,<*.txt>);

#  Cut off header and footer of $files [1] to $files[$#files-1], 
#  but only footer of $files[0] and header of $#files[$#files]
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#files; $i++) {

    print 'Opening ' . $files[$i] . "\n";

    open (my $fh, "<", $files[$i]) or die "can't open $file for reading: $!";
    my @lines = <$fh>;
    splice @lines, 0, 1 unless $i == 0;
    splice @lines, -1, 1 unless $i == $#files;

    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        $buff .= $line;
    }
}

# Write the buffer to a new file.
my $allfilename = $cwd.'/Trace.txt';
print 'Writing all files into new file: ' . $allfilename . "\n";

open $outputfile, ">".$allfilename or die "can't write to new file $outputfile: $!";
# Write the buffer into the output file.
print $outputfile $buff;

close $outputfile;
```

Comment: Maybe someone just misklicked or something...anyway your modyfied version of my code works for me, the original files are not being touched, just as I wanted it - and yes, the code is not elegant but I really don't want to redo everything....even though a more elegant solution would be nice, but i'll deal with that when I have time

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outfile = 'Trace.txt';

# Get all files in cwd.
my @files = grep { -f && $_ ne $outfile } <*.txt>;

open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;

for my $file (@files) {
    my @lines = do { local @ARGV = $file; <> };

    shift @lines unless $file eq $files[0];
    pop @lines   unless $file eq $files[-1];

    print $outfh @lines;
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: You also need a check that you're not including the output file into itself.

Comment: @Borodin The filter for output file is included in the grep that initializes `@files`.

Comment: @Miller As much as i appreciate efficient code, in my humble opinion a construct like that `do { local @ARGV = $file; <>};` really has no place here. At least not without an explanation. Even in scripts at work, i would always use the boring "open, assign, close" way, just in case a future colleague with less Perl experience ever is to maintain my code. And i would argue that here, the target audience are indeed people with less experience. Worst thing, it is not even googleable for a curious rookie.

Comment: @DeVadder I laud your efforts for creating readable code, and kudos to you for evangelizing it.  It's probably my primary motivation as well.  However, there needs to be a deeper understanding of all rules and motivations that allows for exceptions.  I could've just as easily done `do { open my $fh, '<', $file; <$fh> };`.  However, while one shouldn't be cavalier with the deeper features of perl, one needn't be afraid of them either if they're intentional about usage.

Comment: @Miller I was certainly not suggesting to evade your construct, especially if one knows exactly what one is doing. But i stand by my opinion that in an environment aimed at readers not deeply familiar with Perl, it helps if code is either self-explanatory or, well, explained in some other way. Especially as like in this case, it is almost impossible for a curious newbie to google and find out what that line does quickly. My original comment may not have been clear there. I do not think that one should not do it, i just think that here, one should explain it or add a link or comment or w/e.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that you didn't really want your original files modified when I answered [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190016).

I don't understand why you've gone back to accumulating all the text in a buffer before printing it, or why you've removed `use strict`, which is essential to any well-written Perl code.

Here's my previous solution modified to leave the input data untouched.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my @files = grep -f, glob '*.txt';

my $all_filename = 'Trace.txt';
open my $out_fh, '>', $all_filename or die qq{Unable to open "$all_filename" for output: $!};

for my $i ( 0 .. $#files ) {

  my $file = $files[$i];
  next if $file eq $all_filename;

  print "Opening $file\n";

  tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $file or die qq{Can't open "$file": $!};
  my ($start, $end) = (0, $#lines);
  ++$start unless $i == 0;
  --$end   unless $i == $#files;

  print $out_fh "$_\n" for @lines[$start..$end];
}

close $out_fh;
```

Comment: tried your previous solution from the other thread, but it didnt print anything to the output trace.txt file

Comment: @Buitenlander: I wish you had said so before. I have looked again and found a simple bug in it which is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Miller's answer, but most suitable for large files.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outfile = 'Trace.txt';

# Get all files in cwd.
my @files = grep { -f && $_ ne $outfile } <*.txt>;

open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;

my $counter = 0;
for my $file (@files) {
        open my $fh, '<', $file;
        my ($line, $prev) = ('', '');
        my $l = 0;
        while ($line = <$fh>) {
                print $outfh $prev unless $l++ == 1 and $counter > 0;
                $prev = $line;
        }
        $counter++;
        print $outfh $prev if $counter == @files and $l > 0;
        close $fh;
}
```